# How to create unique nodes and relationships by csv file imported in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello I was trying to import some data in csv file to neo4j in my ubuntu 12.04.

The csv file is a two column data file with no header its format is like:

```
12ffew3213,232rwe13
12ffew3213,5yur2ru2r
rwerwerw3,432rwe13
rwerwerw3,5yur2ru2r
```

the thing is the data in row 0 and row 1 is not unique, for example the data may be 3000 lines and only has 100 unique row0 value and 300 unique row1 value.

And I want to build a graph with unique 100 row0 nodes and 300 row1 nodes and 3000 relationships between those nodes(if 12ffew3213,232rwe13 appears twice there are 2 edges).

Since I am new to neo4j and Cypher. After I tried with CREATE and MERGE for a while I still cannot build UNIQUE nodes. I used something like

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/nate/Downloads/file.csv' AS line
MERGE (:A { number: toString(line[0])})-[:LIKES]->(:B { ID: toString(line[1])})
```

Any ideas??Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what you do.

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///home/nate/Downloads/file.csv' AS line
MERGE (n:A {number : line[0]})
WITH line, n
MERGE (m:B {ID : line[1]})
WITH m,n
MERGE (n)-[:LIKES]->(m);
```

You first create or match the `:A` node, then create or match the `:B` node, then create or match the relationship. The `WITH` clauses collect the results at each point in the sequence to use in the next. To find out more about `WITH` clauses, read [Section 9.5 in the Neo4j Manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-with.html).

Comment: Nice answer. Is there any way to do this WITH HEADER?

Answer (score 1):

The same for csv with header. If our header is 'head1','head2' our code will be:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///home/nate/Downloads/file.csv' AS line
MERGE (n:A {number : line.head1})
WITH line, n
MERGE (m:B {ID : line.head2})
WITH m,n
MERGE (n)-[:LIKES]->(m);
```