# Error creating relationships over huge dataset

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My question is similar to the one pointed here :

[Creating unique node and relationship NEO4J over huge dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013284/creating-unique-node-and-relationship-neo4j-over-huge-dataset?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have 2 tables **Entity** (Entities.txt) & **Relationships** (EntitiesRelationships_Updated.txt) which looks like below: Both the tables are inside an import folder within the Neo4j database. What I am trying to do is load the tables using the load csv command and then create relationships.

As in the table below: If ParentID is 0, it means that ENT_ID does not have a parent. If it is populated, then it has a parent. For example in the table below, ENT_ID = 3 is the parent of ENT_ID = 4 and ENT_ID = 1 is the parent of ENT_ID = 2

```
**Entity Table**
ENT_ID  Name  PARENTID
1      ABC     0     
2      DEF     1
3      GHI     0
4      JKG     3



**Relationship Table**
RID ENT_IDPARENT ENT_IDCHILD 
 1     1        2
 2     3        5
```

The Entity table has 2 million records and the relationship tables has about 400K lines

Each RID has a particular tag associated with it. For example RID = 1 has it that the relation is **A** FATHER_OF **B**; RID = 2 has it that the relation is **A** MOTHER_OF **B**. Similarly there are 20 such RIDs associated.

Both of these are in txt format.

My first step is to load the entity table. I used the following script:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Entities.txt" AS Entity FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (n:Entity{ENT_ID: toInt(Entity.ENT_ID),NAME: Entity.NAME,PARENTID: toInt(Entity.PARENTID)})
```

This query works fine. It takes about 10 minutes to load 2.8mil records. The next step I do is to index the records:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Entity(PARENTID)
CREATE INDEX ON :Entity(ENT_ID)
```

This query runs fine as well. Following this I tried creating the relationships from the relationship table using a similar query as in the above link:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///EntitiesRelationships_Updated.txt" AS Rships FIELDTERMINATOR '|' 
MATCH (n:A {ENT_IDPARENT : Rships.ENT_IDPARENT})
with Entity, n
MATCH (m:B {ENT_IDCHILD : Rships.ENT_IDCHILD})
with m,n
MERGE (n)-[r:RELATION_OF]->(m);
```

As I do this, my query keeps running for about an hour and it stops at a particular size(in my case 2.2gb) I followed this query based on the link above. This includes the edit from the solution below and still does not work

I have one more query, which would be as follows (Based on the above link). I run this query as I want to create a relationship based of the Entity table

```
PROFILE
MATCH(Entity)
MATCH (a:Entity {ENT_ID : Entity.ENT_ID})
WITH Entity, a
MATCH (b:Entity {PARENTID : Entity.PARENTID})
WITH a,b
MERGE (a)-[r:PARENT_OF]->(b)
```

While I tried running this query, I get a Java Heap Space Error. Unfortunately, I have not been able to get the solution for these.

Could you please advice if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Something seems to be wrong or missing in your question. When you load from `EntitiesRelationships_Updated.txt`, you are matching on nodes with the `A` and `B` labels, but you never showed the creation of those nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query allows you to take advantage of your `:Entity(ENT_ID)` index:

```
MATCH (child:Entity)
WHERE child.PARENTID > 0
WITH child.PARENTID AS pid, child
MATCH (parent:Entity {ENT_ID : pid})
MERGE (parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child);
```

Cypher does not use indices when the property value comes from another node. To get around that, the above query uses a `WITH` clause to represent `child.PARENTID` as a variable (`pid`). The time complexity of this query should be O(N). You original query has a complexity of O(N * N).

[EDITED]

If the above query takes too long or encounters errors that might be related to running out of memory, try this variant, which creates 1000 new relationships at a time. You can change `1000` to any number that is workable for you.

```
MATCH (child:Entity)
WHERE child.PARENTID > 0 AND NOT ()-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
WITH child.PARENTID AS pid, child
LIMIT 1000
MATCH (parent:Entity {ENT_ID : pid})
CREATE (parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
RETURN COUNT(*);
```

The `WHERE` clause filters out `child` nodes that already have a parent relationship. And the `MERGE` operation has been changed to a simpler `CREATE` operation, since we have already ascertained that the relationship does not yet exist. The query returns a count of the number of relationships created. If the result is less than `1000`, then all parent relationships have been created.

Finally, to make the repeated queries automated, you can install the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) plugin on the neo4j server and use the `apoc.periodic.commit` procedure, which will repeatedly invoke a query until it returns 0. In this example, I use a `limit` parameter of 10000:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
 "MATCH (child:Entity)
  WHERE child.PARENTID > 0 AND NOT ()-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
  WITH child.PARENTID AS pid, child
  LIMIT {limit}
  MATCH (parent:Entity {ENT_ID : pid})
  CREATE (parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
  RETURN COUNT(*);",
{limit: 10000});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking time to provide this response. However, when I used EXPLAIN to understand the results of the query, it sort of looked relevant, as it gave me like 70k relationships, However, it gives me an error: Error: undefined - undefined. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: cybersam, I was under the impression my query for this is about the same as yours, yet the EXPLAIN on your query provides a more correct-looking number of relationships to be created. Do you know if there's a difference in processing between aliasing the PARENTID then using that in the ENT_ID match vs using `ENT_ID: child.PARENTID`? That would be a very helpful thing to know.

Comment: Huh. Didn't know it wouldn't use the index when attempting to use a node property directly. I hope neo4j fixes that.

Comment: @Sharath: I don't get any errors from `EXPLAIN`. Maybe you need to update your neo4j version?

Comment: Cybersam: I am currently using 3.0.1. Is there a more recent version? Could you also help me on the first part of the code?

Comment: I think the error is from attempting to run the query after removing EXPLAIN. I think I've seen that undefined error come up in cases when memory runs out. Even with the usage of indexing, I think this requires some kind of batching solution, either repeatedly executing the query with LIMIT (the query will need to remove the PARENTID field so it doesn't get picked up later), or by APOC Procedures periodic commit.

Comment: I ended up using Limit 100000, it has been running but it has been nearly 20 minutes and it still has not completed. I don't understand why you would be removing the PARENTID field. One parent can have many children.Wouldn't removing the parentid affect it? Also I was of the thought that Neo4j is fast. But it has completely proved the otherwise :/

Comment: Could you also tell me why the solution as per this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090255/how-to-create-unique-nodes-and-relationships-by-csv-file-imported-in-neo4j   doesn't work??

Comment: One parent can have many children, but it seems like a single child can only have one parent. The idea with using LIMIT is to execute the query on a subset, and once the relationship has been created, you don't need the PARENTID field anymore, and by removing it you ensure it won't get processed when you run the query for the next set to process.

Comment: Regarding the question you linked to, the answer on that question addresses it. What it comes down to is that MERGE, when applied to a pattern, tries to match on the entire pattern (provided it's not matching on existing variables), and if it can't, it tries to create the entire pattern. What you're doing in your query should be fine, as it's only trying to merge the relationship between existing nodes.

Comment: How much longer do you think I should be expecting to wait for the above query to get completed??

Comment: As you said, I was just trying to create relationship using the query. But still it errored out. Could you help me understand why so? This is regarding your answer to my question on Merge

Comment: I think you'll have to figure out if there's something wrong with your query first. Why don't you try the query (adding `LIMIT 100` to the end of the WITH clause) and PROFILE it (expanding all nodes in the profile view), and add it to your description, along with the execution time?

Comment: See my edit answer, which proposes a query that only creates a certain number of relationships at a time. I used 1000, but you may want to try something higher.

Comment: I have added your edit answer with 100K as the number for limiting relationships. I am letting it run right now and been 5 minutes I hope it gets done within next 15 minutes. Is there any setting in the configuration I should change to increase the speed??

Comment: The 100k may have been too high, especially when you were seeing 30 minute+ waits before. You may want to try scaling up from something smaller. LIMIT 100 ought to be zippy. LIMIT 1000 decent. Even 10k ought to work fairly well. In any case, try starting low rather than high.

Comment: Hey Guys, Thanks a bunch for taking time to help me out. But I have no idea why on earth it takes so long to run? I ran it with 100, 1000 and 10K for half hour each and still no result. I wanted to try it all before reaching out to you guys again! :(

Comment: If it's timing out with LIMIT 100, then there's definitely something off here. Does it finish with LIMIT 10? And if not 10 then LIMIT 5?

Comment: I don't think that LIMIT is in the right place. Instead of being at the end, can you move it to right after the WITH clause? Try with 10 first, and if it finishes faster than before, PROFILE it when you run in next and add it to your description.

Comment: Thank you, @InverseFalcon. The `LIMIT` was most certainly in the wrong place, since the `COUNT` function would result in just a single result row, so the `LIMIT` value would never be reached. I have altered my answer to put it right after the `WITH`, which should work as intended.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for the edit. Sorry for not reaching out to you earlier. But I added the above edited script. So it works fine with Limit 100 and 10K, but 100K it fails. But as per what you have mentioned @InverseFalcon, I added profile and removed the Limit 1000 and ran the script, I got the Java Heap Space Error. Sorry but I am novice at this and I am learning. I mean am I expected to rerun the above script (with Limit 1000) untill I get Count 0 (keep running the script "N" number of times??) Like Would there be an easier way than that?

Comment: Yes, by using the APOC Procedures library (you'll need to make sure you're using a version compatible with the neo4j version). As mentioned in my answer, there is a periodic.commit() function which will execute a query repeatedly until there are no results returned. You'll just have to make sure the query has a means of detecting when the node has already been processed (such as the presence of a relationship in the query above). As for the PROFILE, you should definitely keep the LIMIT in place when you run it.

Comment: @InverseFalcon is correct again. I have updated my answer yet again to add an example of what the APOC procedure call would look like.

Comment: Thanks a bunch you guys.. You guys are awesome. It would be great if you could help me out on the part on creating relationships using the Relationship table. USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///EntitiesRelationships_Updated.txt" AS Rships FIELDTERMINATOR '|' 
MATCH (parent:Entity {ENT_ID : Rships.ENT_IDPARENT})
MATCH (child:Entity {ENT_ID : Rships.ENT_IDCHILD})
MERGE (parent)-[r:RELATION_OF]->(child)
ON CREATE SET r.RID = Rships.RID;  This does not work

Comment: You should create a new question, and provide complete details about what is not working. This question is really just about the heap space issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your entity creation Cypher looks fine, as do your indexes.

I am rather confused about the last two Cypher fragments though.

Since your relationships have a specific label or id associated with them, it's probably best to add your relationships by loading from the relationship table data, though the node labels in your query (A and B) aren't used in your Entity creation and aren't in your graph, and neither are ENT_IDPARENT or ENT_IDCHILD fields. Looks like this isn't really the Cypher you used, but an example you built off of?

I'd change this relationship creation query to this, setting the type property of the relationship for post-processing later (this assumes that there can only be one :RELATION_OF relation between the same two nodes):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///EntitiesRelationships_Updated.txt" AS Rships FIELDTERMINATOR '|' 
MATCH (parent:Entity {ENT_ID : Rships.ENT_IDPARENT})
MATCH (child:Entity {ENT_ID : Rships.ENT_IDCHILD})
MERGE (parent)-[r:RELATION_OF]->(child)
ON CREATE SET r.RID = Rships.RID;
```

Later on, if you like, you can match on your relationships with an RID, and add the corresponding type ("FATHER_OF", "MOTHER_OF", etc) property.

As for creating the :PARENT_OF relationship, you're doing some extra match on an Entity variable bound to every single node in your graph - get rid of that.

Instead, use this:

```
PROFILE
// first, match on all Entities with a PARENTID property
MATCH(child:Entity)
WHERE EXISTS(child.PARENTID)
// next, find the parent for each child by the child's PARENTID
WITH child
MATCH (parent:Entity {ENT_ID : child.PARENTID})
MERGE (parent)-[:PARENT_OF]->(child)
// lastly remove the parentid from the child, so it won't be reprocessed
// if we run the query again.
REMOVE child.PARENTID
```

EDITED the above query to use an existence check on child.PARENTID, and to remove child.PARENTID after the corresponding relationship has been created.

If you need a solution that uses batching, you could do this manually (adding `LIMIT 100000` to your `WITH child` line, or you could install the [APOC Procedures Library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and use its [periodic.commit() function](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_job_management_and_periodic_execution) to batch your processing.

Comment: So I ran the first query, it runs successfully. However, your second query is wrong. It gives me a Java Heap Space Error..

Comment: Likely not wrong, but it is an operation that will be operating on millions of nodes, so we should be able to batch it to avoid blowing the heap. First, could you change the PROFILE to EXPLAIN and take a look?

Comment: Also, looking at your description again, does a PARENTID of 0 indicate that there is no parent for the entity? If so, then we can remove entries from the relevant nodes: `MATCH (e:Entity) WHERE e.PARENTID = 0 REMOVE e.PARENTID`.

Comment: So I changed it to explain:

It blows up the create relationship to 404,531,421,320 rows. That is wrong. Could you tell me why that happens

Comment: Also, the first query takes really long to finish. Is there anyway to make it run faster? Even that I believe may be wrong because of the number of rows using EXPLAIN : 80,906,284,864 rows. I do not think this is the right number of answers. Can you please help? Thanks for your time

Comment: I know that my dataset would have 0 if there is no PARENTID. Now Does the EXIST() function take that also into consideration?

Comment: No, it doesn't, which is why you should remove that property from your entity nodes when it's 0. That should also help out the processing time on the relationship creation query since it will be working on a smaller dataset.

Comment: The number in your EXPLAIN doesn't quite sound right either. First, let's confirm how many nodes we're working with `MATCH (e:Entity) RETURN COUNT(e)`, then ensure that the entity ID is unique (I'm assuming it's supposed to be) and that the creation query did the right thing `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:Entity) ASSERT e.ENT_ID IS UNIQUE`

Comment: Match(e:Entity) Return Count(e) gives me 2844403. Also since I have already created Index on ENT_ID, it doesnt allow me to create the constraint

Comment: Does the entity count match the count in your source? If not, then something may be going wrong with :Entity node creation. That may be a reason to try dropping your index and adding a unique constraint (again, as long as ENT_ID is meant to be unique across :Entities). Unique constraints will also create an index.

Comment: The Entity Count matches the count in my source. I can drop the index and create the unique constraint again.

Comment: Even dropping the index and recreate the unique constraint and running it again did not work

Comment: Do you mean that you weren't able to create the unique constraint, or do you mean that adding the unique constraint didn't change anything? As you said the node count matches what you expect, so more than likely your nodes were created correctly, and a unique constraint, while correct, won't be the way to fix this issue.