# Creating Relationships over already existing Huge Dataset

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a table - Entity(Entities.txt) which I have already loaded into Neo4j using the "LOAD CSV" command.
The structure of the Entity table is like below:

```
**Entity Table**
ENT_ID  Name  PARENTID
1      ABC     0     
2      DEF     1
3      GHI     0
4      JKG     3
```

I have another table which is in the following format:

```
**Relationship Table**
RelationID ENT_IDPARENT ENT_IDCHILD 
 1     1        2
 2     3        5
 3     4        6
```

What I need to is create relationships over the existing nodes. Each of the RelationID stand for a particular type of relationship. FOr example: RelationID = 1 means ENT_IDPARENT = 1 is the FATHER_OF ENT_IDCHILD = 2. Similarly, each of the other RIDs stand for some other relationship. The table has 40 RIDs.

Based on the link:
[How to create unique nodes and relationships by csv file imported in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090255/how-to-create-unique-nodes-and-relationships-by-csv-file-imported-in-neo4j)

I tried writing the syntax below to create relationships.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///C:/Users/ssubramana001/Desktop/EntitiesRelationships_Updated.txt" AS Entity FIELDTERMINATOR '|' 
MATCH (n:Entity {ENT_ID: Entity.ENT_IDPARENT})
WITH Entity, n
MATCH (m:Entity {ENT_ID: Entity.ENT_IDCHILD})
WITH m,n
MERGE (n)-[r:SON_OF]->(m)
```

This query does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you tried cutting parts, like removing the matches and returning the first lines instead to make sure it's read OK, using `RETURN Entity LIMIT 10`? Then matching the first node and returning it? Etc. By the way, it would be more readable if you used a variable name for the line that's not the same as the label of the nodes (`Entity`).

Comment: I get an error Java Heap Space after it runs for about an hour or so. when I did use a different variable name and label, it ended up creating a relationship even though it errored out, but the relationship was created under the label name and not under Entity

Comment: You may also want to use more descriptive variables names, such as "parent" and "child", as it makes it easier to avoid creating the wrong relationships. In your description, you are saying that node n is the son of node m, yet you're matching the parent id to node n, so your relationship is backwards. Also, unless all children in your CSV are male, I'm not sure your SON_OF relationship is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, I don't have your actual file with millions of lines, but this definitely works with your example:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///relationships.csv" AS line
WITH toInt(line.ENT_IDPARENT) AS parentId, toInt(line.ENT_IDCHILD) AS childId
WHERE line.RelationID = '1'
MATCH (p:Entity {ENT_ID: parentId}), (c:Entity {ENT_ID: childId})
MERGE (p)-[:FATHER_OF]->(c);
```

Note that it converts numeric values as you did for the node creation [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107132/error-creating-relationships-over-huge-dataset).

It really feels strange that you'd get a OutOfMemory error with `USING PERIODIC COMMIT`, but you could try splitting your CSV file into smaller ones to see if it also happens after importing them all. Maybe your Neo4j instance doesn't have enough memory to manage all those nodes at all (it would have to be really limited, I guess)? Could you update the question with the exact OutOfMemory error, **including the message**? You could be running out of PermGen or MetaSpace (depending on your Java version), or hitting the swap and having GC take too much time because of that.