# Neo4j Weighted Interactions

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, edges

I have a large CSV file which looks like

```
Node1    Node2    Weight
1         2         10 
2         3         15
1         3         5
3         10        20
etc...
```

I would like to create a graph on Neo4j that show the interactions between the Node1 and 2 Weighted by the column Weight.

I created the interactions thanks to this post [How to create unique nodes and relationships by csv file imported in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090255/how-to-create-unique-nodes-and-relationships-by-csv-file-imported-in-neo4j?rq=1)

But I don't have the weights yet

I tried the following

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ewqrwqsa.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:A {number : line.Node1})
WITH line, n
MERGE (m:B {ID : line.Node2})
WITH line, m, n 
MERGE (l:W {weight : toInteger(line.Weight)})
WITH l,m,n
MERGE (n)-[:Related(l)]->(m);
```

But it doesn't work...
Thanks !

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work" providing a [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to add a property to the relationship. Try this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ewqrwqsa.csv" AS line
MERGE (n:A {number : line.Node1})
MERGE (m:B {ID : line.Node2})
MERGE (n)-[r:Related]->(m)
SET r.weight = toInteger(line.Weight);
```

Comment: Is there any command to visualize this ?

Comment: This just creates/matches to the relationships and sets the weight property on them. To visualize after relationships are created, you would just use a normal MATCH on the pattern with the nodes in question and the :Related relationship.